# Cannot specialize struct

Tags: c++, template-specialization

Why this doesn't work?

```
template <class T>
struct Low;

template <>
struct Low<int> {};//Here I'm trying to specialize for int

int main()
{
Low<1> a;

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Low<int> a;` will work - Your template takes a *type* not an *integral* argument.

Answer (score 4):

```
Low<1> a;
```

Your class template `Low` expects TYPE, not INTEGRAL VALUE!

If you want to use that way, you've to define your class template as:

```
template <int N>
struct Low {};
```

This allows you to write `Low<1>`, `Low<2>`, `Low<400>`, etc.

---

If you define `Low` as,

```
template <class T>
struct Low;
```

Then you've to provide a *type* when instantiating it. For example, `Low<char>`, `Low<unsigned int>`, etc.

So notice the difference how they're defined in each case, and how  they are instantiated!

Answer (score 3):

There is a difference between `Low<1>` and `Low<int>`.

You will need to write a specialization for `Low<1>`, but that is not possible since the original template takes a type as the first parameter not a value.